# HTML how: iframe and contents of iframe resizes when the page window is resized

Tags: html, iframe, resize

Okay, so i have these sample html pages.

-main.html

-framepage.html

I was wondering what i can add to make the contents of the iframe(from main.html) display the whole page of "framepage.html" and have the iframe along with the contents of framepage.html also resize when you resize the net browser window.

Here are the codes:

main.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<head>
<title>main</title>

<body style="background-color:gray;">

<iframe style="frame" src="framepage.html" scrolling="no" width="800px" height="600px" name="window" noresize frameborder="0">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>


</body>

</html>
```

And the framepage.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<head>
<title>lalala</title>

<style>
.cap {
 position:relative;
 top:10px;
 left:6px;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
</br>
<div style="position:relative;left:1220px;top:-15px;">

<div style="width:390px; height:215px; background-color:blue;">
<p class="cap" style="font-weight:bold;">Frame 3</p>
</div>

<div style="width:390px; height:438px; background-color:red;">
<p class="cap" style="font-weight:bold;">Frame 4</p>
</div>

</div>

<div style="width:1160px; height:405px; position:relative;top:-699px;left:35px;background-color:green;">
<p class="cap" style="font-weight:bold;">Frame 1</p>
</div>


<div style="position:relative;top:-699px;left:35px; width:1160px; height:250px;background-color:yellow;">
<p class="cap" style="font-weight:bold;">Frame 2</p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you could use relative values instead absolute values (eg. use 100% instead of 800px). Refer to the below code snippet. This essentially make the size of iframe to be 100% fit to the size of the browser (and main.html) and then the framepage.html should have  blocks defined as relative values as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<head>
<title>main</title>

<body style="background-color:gray;">

<iframe style="frame" src="framepage.html" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="600px" name="window" noresize frameborder="0">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>


</body>

</html>
```

If you are not limited to use particular browser types (and so css3 can be used), then you can use "flex box" which gives more flexible options for displaying contents like your divs. Refer to the url here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp
and here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for more information.

Feel free to ask any questions regarding flex box or css. Hope this helps.